# sending null values through JSON that will be accepted by mysql DB DATETIME column

Tags: javascript, mysql, ecmascript-6

In javaScript I have this command:

```
  rowInfo[lastLogin] = ''
```

the lastLogin label corresponds to a MySQL database table column called lastLogin which is a DATETIME one. I suspect this is going to give me trouble after I send rowInfo back to the server using axios and JSON:

```
    var postAxios = axios({
                        method: 'post',
                        url:     httpLink,
                        params: {tableName: 'customer'},
                        data: rowInfo
                        }             
                    ) ...
```

I wish I could assign a NULL db value to  rowInfo[lastLogin]  but is it going to be possible to the mySQL database accept the JS NULL value? The lastLogin DB column has no constraints. It can accept null values and DATETIME values.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-comparison - don't know if this helps... Table 11.2 JSON Conversion Rules

Comment: Empty string `''` serializes to `""` in JSON.  That is not the same as `null`.  Can you not set `rowInfo[lastLogin] = NULL`?  I would assume JavaScript null would serialize to JSON null. (DBA here, not really a JavaScript expert.)